# Does a Webview have separate Surface?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am confused with my understanding related to webview and surface and request someone to clarify me on this:

If I have a webview in a layout which I inflate on top of my activity layout, in the same activity context, does it have its own separate surface for drawing things or it uses the same surface of the window, the activity has?

As simple as, by default does the webview has separate surface apart for the the surface the window of the activity has?

Thank you for any help